# D3js v4: scaleOrdinal does not have the rangePoints()

Tags: d3.js

I'm migrating the parallel coordinates source code [here](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281) to the newest d3js version (d3js 4.5.0). I'm stuck to this line:

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, width], 1)
```

It seems that in d3js v4 the `rangePoints` function does not exist anymore. I can change to d3.[scaleOrdinal](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/src/ordinal.js)(), but it has only the `range` function, not the `rangePoints` function. Any clue on for this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In D3 v4, two new scales were created: `scaleBand` and `scalePoint`, which now have some of the features that `scale.ordinal` had in version 3 (among them `rangePoints`).

It's documented in the [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> Similarly, the ordinal.rangePoints and ordinal.rangeRoundPoints methods have been replaced with a new subclass of ordinal scale: point scales. The following code in 3.x:
>
> ```
> var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
> .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
> .rangePoints([0, width]);
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to this in 4.0:
>
> ```
> var x = d3.scalePoint()
> .domain(["a", "b", "c"])
> .range([0, width]);
> ```

Therefore, the scale you need here is [scalePoint](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#point-scales):

> Point scales are a variant of band scales with the bandwidth fixed to zero. Point scales are typically used for scatterplots with an ordinal or categorical dimension.

Thus, change your scale to:

```
var x = scalePoint()
    .range([0, width])
    .padding(.1);
```

Pay attention to the `padding`: in a point scale, `range` accepts only the range array, not the padding anymore.